# Windows 7 Home Premium x64 Disk Partitioning

Tags: windows-7, laptop, partitioning, 64-bit

I'm having new Dell studio 1749 laptop with one partition (C). there is another backup partition - hidden. 
How can I create new partition for all the files and the other stuff to be seperated from the C partition? I'm looking for a clean and simple way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to first defrag your hard drive -this moves everything to the front of the drive.

Next, go in to `Computer Management > Disk Management` and right click the main partition and choose `Shrink`.

After you have done this, create a new partition in the now free space.

This should work, but if this doesn't work, try downloading and using [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

If you want more details on any step, please say and I will go in to it in more detail.

Comment: I will check this :-)  
So, I understand from you that I don't have to install third party application? just in case that the steps you wrote won't work?  Will those steps might make my disk corrupted?  
thanks!

Comment: As long as your computer doesn't crash or get unplugged during the middle, all of these steps should not cause any damage.

Comment: Do you know if I'll be able to roll back the new partition into the currrent main partition?

Comment: At any point you should be able to remove/delete the new one and grow the original one. FYI, the reason I say to do defrag first is otherwise, you will only be able to shrink up to wherever the last byte is written... defragging first means you can shrink a lot more.

Comment: thanks :-) I'll try this is the next days. many thanks for your kind help!